# Get the highest version number from Minecraft Server reply Query string

Tags: php, minecraft

I'm creating a Minecraft server listing website, which queries each Minecraft Server and gets a reply containing info such us online players, MOTD, etc. Among this info is a string containing info about the Client versions that can join. Typical strings are like this:

```
1.14.4
BungeeCord 1.8.x-1.14.x
§cWe support: 1.8 - 1.14.4
Waterfall 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.10.x, 1.11.x, 1.12.x
TacoSpigot 1.8.8
```

I'm looking to write a piece of code that would strip these down and leave just the highest major supported version. For instance 1.14, or 1.12

I'm thinking preg_replace, maybe, but I have no idea how to approach this, any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could split each string by a bunch of potential delimiters and just grab the last item from the split out array: `$highestVersionInLine=end(preg_split( '/[ ,-]/', $lineFromResponse));` Also, this might be a better usecase for python and cron where you poll your list on a set frequency and store the results to a file or database table where your php can pull from. `php` can probably get the job done here, but it's a bit of a light-weight for hitting api's and making sense of ugly responses.

Comment: Worked! Left me with a string like 1.14.x or 1.8.2
I then used preg_match('/^(1.(5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20))/', $version, $matches); to keep just the major version.
Thanks!